# how to read and display image vector data as a livestream in linux

Tags: linux, camera, spi, bounding-box

I am using a evaluation board that has a camera on it. It sends the jpg data via SPI to my PC and im trying to write a linux C++ program to open a viewer to view the data as a picture during run time. (it should constantly show the new data that is transmitted via spi).

Is there any image viewers that i can use that allows me to call it in my C++ code and pass the byte `vector<uint8>&img` address to it?

The next step would be for it to read another stream of data which contains the coordinates of the bounding box and plot it together with the image.

Answer (score 0):

I used the magick c++ version to edit and display the image via a blob. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).